# webGL ignore back facing?

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

I have got myself a nice shape using webGL, but when i use the line strip option, I'm also get triangles from the back, how can I just not draw back face? the shape is really hard to understand when so many triangles being drawn :(

I'm using

```
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, myBuffer.items);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, myBuffer.items);
```

and it looks horrible, so i just use

```
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
```

But it still looks very hard to understand,

any help will be great :)

Canvas

Comment: Are you using a depth buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok, i got around it, what i did was create a small piece of code to just generate a weird colour for each triangle like so

```
            for(i=1;i<shapeFaces.length;i++)
    {
        colors[colors.length] = new Array((i*0.02), (i*0.02), (i*0.02), 1.0 );
    }
```

So now all the faces are filled, but I can actually see my shape :), sorry for the bother, but cheers for the help